# When I'm sieging a province, what this sign near my army means?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

**What this sign near my army means when I'm sieging a province ?**

I first thought it was a decorative emblem, but it'n not always there when sieging.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means you've broken down the walls, and you can assault the fort if you want.  Look close when you first start a seige and you'll see an icon that's an unbroken wall.

See the details on breaching the wall [here](http://www.eu4wiki.com/Land_warfare#Effects)